# Why is affectedRows takes time to update

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) states:

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated.

However, while using it, I get a different result. For a same multiple primary unique key, it takes 5 or 6 update before considering like an update and not a new insert. 
I first thought that it may nodejs with the [mysql](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql) package which would be bugged?

However, I noticed that through the mysql shell, I get the same type of error:

```
INSERT INTO table SET `master_id` = 119, `slave_id` = 1221829, 
`date` = '2014-09-18', `type` = '42', `threshold` = '18', 
`value` = 18.3536, `ratio` = '1.96'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = (value + VALUES(value)) / 2, 
ratio = (ratio + VALUES(ratio)) / 2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

INSERT INTO alerts SET `master_id` = 119, `slave_id` = 1221829, 
`date` = '2014-09-18', `type` = '42', `threshold` = '18', 
`value` = 18.3536, `ratio` = '1.96'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = (value + VALUES(value)) / 2, 
ratio = (ratio + VALUES(ratio)) / 2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

INSERT INTO alerts SET `master_id` = 119, `slave_id` = 1221829, 
`date` = '2014-09-18', `type` = '42', `threshold` = '18', 
`value` = 18.3536, `ratio` = '1.96'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = (value + VALUES(value)) / 2, 
ratio = (ratio + VALUES(ratio)) / 2;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Is it because it is not advised to use ON DUPLICATE KEY for a multiple primary key as stated below?

> In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
>   clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.

Or is it because it is the sames values? Or because the interval between two insertions is too short (~ 10 seconds)?

My table has the following primary key: {master_id, slave_id, date, type}

I really don't get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get 0 affected rows, because UPDATE statement does not change a value.

> For UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value by default is the
>   number of rows actually changed. If you specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS
>   flag to mysql_real_connect() when connecting to mysqld, the
>   affected-rows value is the number of rows “found”; that is, matched by
>   the WHERE clause.